# How to dispatch an action from inside getInitialProps?

Tags: javascript, redux, next.js, next-redux-wrapper

I am trying to implement Redux in a Next.js app and have problems getting the dispatch function to work in `getInitialProps`. The store is returned as undefined for some reason that I cannot figure out. I am using next-redux-wrapper. I have followed the documentation on next-redux-wrapper GitHub page but somewhere on the way it goes wrong. I know the code is working - I used axios to directly fetch the `artPieces` and then it worked just fine but I want to use Redux instead. I am changing an react/express.js app to a Next.js app where I will use the API for the basic server operations needed. This is just a small blog app.

Here is my `store.js`:

```
import { createStore } from 'redux';
import { createWrapper, HYDRATE } from 'next-redux-wrapper';

// create your reducer
const reducer = (state = { tick: 'init' }, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case HYDRATE:
            return { ...state, ...action.payload };
        case 'TICK':
            return { ...state, tick: action.payload };
        default:
            return state;
    }
}; 

// create a makeStore function  
const makeStore = (context) => createStore(reducer);

// export an assembled wrapper
export const wrapper = createWrapper(makeStore, { debug: true });
```

And here is the `_app.js`:

```
import './styles/globals.css';
import { wrapper } from '../store';

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
    return <Component {...pageProps} />;
}

export default wrapper.withRedux(MyApp);
```

And finally here is where it does not work. Trying to call dispatch on the context to a sub component to `_app.js`:

```
import React from 'react';
import { ArtPiecesContainer } from './../components/ArtPiecesContainer';
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import axios from 'axios';
import { getArtPieces } from '../reducers';

const Art = ({ data, error }) => {
    return (
        <>
            <ArtPiecesContainer artPieces={data} />
        </>
    );
};

export default Art;

Art.getInitialProps = async ({ ctx }) => {
    await ctx.dispatch(getArtPieces());

    console.log('DATA FROM GETARTPIECES', data);

    return { data: ctx.getState() };
};
```

Comment: Please revise your post title to ask a clear, _specific_ question rather than just listing tags.

Comment: Have you tried wrapping the `getinitialProps` function with [`wrapper.getInitialPageProps`](https://github.com/kirill-konshin/next-redux-wrapper#pagegetinitialprops)?

Comment: That was the correct answer. I read so many posts but hot the actual documentation thoroughly...

Comment: There is no green tick next to the comments/answers. W h y ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should probably work with `"next-redux-wrapper": "^7.0.5"`

**_app.js**

```
import { wrapper } from '../store'
import React from 'react';
import App from 'next/app';

class MyApp extends App {
  static getInitialProps = wrapper.getInitialAppProps(store => async ({Component, ctx}) => {
    return {
      pageProps: {
        // Call page-level getInitialProps
        // DON'T FORGET TO PROVIDE STORE TO PAGE
        ...(Component.getInitialProps ? await Component.getInitialProps({...ctx, store}) : {}),
        // Some custom thing for all pages
        pathname: ctx.pathname,
      },
    };

  });

  render() {
    const {Component, pageProps} = this.props;

    return (
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    );
  }
}

export default wrapper.withRedux(MyApp);
```

and **Index.js**

```
import { useEffect } from 'react'
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux'
import { END } from 'redux-saga'
import { wrapper } from '../store'
import { loadData, startClock, tickClock } from '../actions'
import Page from '../components/page'

const Index = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch()

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(startClock())
  }, [dispatch])

  return <Page title="Index Page" linkTo="/other" NavigateTo="Other Page" />
}

Index.getInitialProps = wrapper.getInitialPageProps(store => async (props) => {
  store.dispatch(tickClock(false))

  if (!store.getState().placeholderData) {
    store.dispatch(loadData())
    store.dispatch(END)
  }

  await store.sagaTask.toPromise()
});


export default Index
```

For the rest of the code you can refer to nextjs/examples/with-redux-saga, but now that I'm posting this answer they're using the older version on **next-redux-wrapper** ( version 6 ).